# How to not always compile all assets on autoload in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I've started my first ember.js project with ember-cli including ember-cli-broccoli-compass to compile my stylesheets with compass. Now that I've done my first styling, my stylesheets need 5 seconds to compile. When I now work on my javascripts and there are any changes to my files, my whole project, including the stylesheets, is re-compiled, which lasts a bit too long for me. So, is there any way to exclude the stylesheets from the compiling process?

**EDIT:**

I don't know this is "the answer", but using https://github.com/quaertym/ember-cli-compass-compiler instead avoids the problem.

Comment: are you developing on a mac or a windows machine?

Comment: Neither one, I'm on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on compass but I think its related to this issue over on ember-cli-less with sourcemaps

https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-less/issues/10

https://github.com/ef4/broccoli-sourcemap-concat/pull/3

The issues have been closed but on a fresh ember new they are still present